# Date filter: wrong format

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this field in my Post model:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), default=datetime.now)
```

In my template I have this:

```
{{ post.created|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

I my settings.py I have this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'
USE_L10N = True
```

But I get this:

th03-0500RCDT_marAMCDTE_maggio-0500RMagAMCDT

Why ?

This is the documentation:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Which version of Django are you on? I see in the 1.2 release notes that some stuff has been deprecated - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#date-format-helper-functions  -- are you on a pre-release version of 1.2 that might still have issues?

Comment: @stevejalim, it's the other way round - the SHORT_DATE_FORMAT stuff is new in 1.2.

Comment: what version of django are you using? `import django; django.get_version()` Your link is documentation for development version.